# If else in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

I have the following function, when I call it's printing out the mess but if the `if` condition is false than it's not going the else branch, what I'm doing wrong?

```
def lidarMessageHandler( self, mess ):
        print( mess );
        #Check if I received the right command
        if( COMMANDTABLE[commandList[self.clientname]['lastcommand']]['id'] == mess['commandName'] ):
            print( 'if' )
            #Check if it's a blocking command            
            commandList[self.clientname]['isready'] = True
            if( self.start ):
                self.waitingForSettingsHandler( mess )
                return                           
        else:
            error = "I waited the answer for the following command %s but I received % command from %s " % self.lastCommand, mess['commandName'], self.clientname
            self.reiseError( error )
            isRunning[self.clientname] = False
            print( 'else' );
```

Comment: It seems valid. The only weird thing I see is `reiseError()`. Shouldn't that be `raiseError()` ?

Comment: Your `else` condition is probably connected with your inner `if`. Check your indentation.

Comment: @Paolo: I guess you are right. Identation is 8 first, then it becomes 4 in the inner level.

Comment: How do you know that the condition is false?

Comment: From the message, I printed out, and the  if statement will be false.

Comment: @iUngi: Move the `print` message to the **top** of the `else` block, to make absolutely sure that no statement before the `print` raises an exception.

Comment: An empty variable caused the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably get an exception here:

```
error = "I waited the answer for the following command %s but I received % command from %s " % self.lastCommand, mess['commandName'], self.clientname
                                                                         ^
```

You should add `s`:

```
error = "I waited the answer for the following command %s but I received %s command from %s " % self.lastCommand, mess['commandName'], self.clientname
                                                                         ^
```

(I assume `mess['commandName']` is a string)

Comment: Yes, it's a string, but I'm not getting this error, because the program not going in the else branch.

Comment: Just to make it clear, have you debugged it and see that it doesn't go the the `else` branch or you only assume?

Answer (score 2):

When the condition in your `if` statement evaluates to `False`, the `else` block is most certainly executed.  What makes you think otherwise?

I suspect that your code raises an exception that you seem to ignore or silence in an outer `try`-`except` block.  For example, the line

```
error = "I waited the answer for the following command %s but I received % command from %s " % self.lastCommand, mess['commandName'], self.clientname
```

will raise a `TypeError`, since you are passing 3 arguments but only have 2 placeholders, as you seem to have forgotten the "s" near "I received % command".

Answer (score 2):

If `"self.reiseError"` actually raises an error, you'll never get to `isRunning[self.clientname] = False`.

By the way, there is no need to use parenthesis in `if` statements as if it was C-syntax-derived language.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be going to the `if` branch but your `print` just isn't getting flushed out of the buffer?

Also, `self.reiseError( error )` looks like a misspelling to me, so you should get an `AttributeError` there.

An indentation error that doesn't show up after the paste to Stack Overflow is also possible.